# laravel echo server Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 302

Tags: laravel

I am trying to build a real-time notification system with laravel 5.8, laravel-echo-server, redis and socket.io

i broadcast the login event, i have tow type of users student and prof

the authenticated function

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
      $event = new UserLoginEvent($user->id);

        broadcast($event)->toOthers();

      if ($user->isProf()) {
          return redirect('/prof/dashboard');
        }

        return redirect('/etudiant/dashboard');
    }
```

broadcast event

```
public function __construct($user)
    {
        
        $this->user = $user;
    }

public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('login');
    }
```

channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('login', function ($user) {
     if(Auth::check()){
        return ['id'=>$user->id];
    }
});
```

in the prof controller i use these middelware

```
public function __construct()
      {

    $this->middleware(['auth','verified']);
    
    $this->middleware('etudiant')->only(['search','rating']);
    $this->middleware('prof')->only(['dashboard']);
    $this->middleware('info')->except(['profil']);

      }
```

prof middelware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         if ( Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isProf() )
         {
             return $next($request);
         }
         return redirect('/');
     }
```

and in the student controller i use

```
 public function __construct()
      {
           $this->middleware(['auth','verified','etudiant']);
    
      }
```

etudiant middelware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
         if ( Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->isProf() )
         {
             return $next($request);
         }
         return redirect('/');
     }
```

when i am trying to connect with student compte the event broadcast normally, but with the prof compte im got this error

```
⚠ [2:52:13 PM] - uCUlo9fp3WNtRMgBAAAA could not be authenticated to presence-login
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='http://localhost:8000/login'" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost:8000/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost:8000/login">http://localhost:8000/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 302
```